# Outlook Subject line turning RED

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Every now and then I get an email where the sender has set a "due date" on the email some how. This causes the email subject line to eventually turn red. This is really useful and generally ensures I don't miss something important but...

Even when the email has been read, replied to, and archived it stays red. Is there a way to mark these emails as done/complete/actioned, and remove the red(overdue) status?

Please note, this is an EMAIL not a TASK there is no follow up flag or anything that I can find to mark them as dealt with.

Comment: I'd never heard of this before but I found out how to send emails with a reminder and when i do it (Outlook 2010) it ends up in my inbox with a little flag next to a little man. Clicking that turns it into a task flag which can then be ticked as done.

Comment: there's no flag on the email, and manually flaging it and marking it complete doesn't do anything.  Subject is still red.

Comment: Hmmm. I think the big question then is what are they doing differently to mark the email with a date. If you ask them how they do it, that should help figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I think they are just flagging it for follow-up before they send.

Comment: Weird; like I said, if you use the "Set follow up for receiver" function it applies a different kind of flag, but still a flag. If they really are just flagging it as standard then maybe there's a problem with your instalation of Outlook?

Comment: Old thread, but -- could it be a 'message expiration' of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned this so far:

#### Once you highlight red message, press <kbd>Insert</kbd> key.

This will mark the message as completed (with green check mark) and **red color disappears.**

Marking the message as complete is more useful than clearing the due date, because you keep the information that this message meant a task before and now the task is completed. Looking into the archive, you can know you followed up the message – you did not overlook it.

Also, inspect set of conditional formatting rules in menu **View** > **View Settings** > **Conditional Formatting...**. Normally, there is only one rule which turns the font red: **Overdue email**. If you have no other red-font rules there, check **Due Date** of your message in **Custom** (flag) dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on message). In case if you have additional red-font rules in conditional formatting rule set, check what condition they use. In any of the above cases, you can temporarily disable the rules by clearing their checkboxes so by step-by-step disabling you can quickly see which rule actually caused the red font.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there's no flag, right-click on message and click on "Clear Flag."  When I tried this, it removed the red color.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double-click on the e-mail to open it, select 'Follow Up' and click 'Mark Complete'
2. Click on the flag on the far-right column of the main Outlook window
3. Find the entry in the to-do bar, right-click and select 'Mark complete'

If none of these work, something has gone wrong.

Comment: Under follow up there is only "Flag Message", and because it is not actually flaged there is no way to mark it complete under the to-do bar.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that they didn't also mark it high-priority?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the email that has the red subject line.
2. Scroll down the menu to the flag icon "Follow Up", then click on "Custom"
3. You should see Start Date and Due Date boxes.  Choose "None".
4. Click OK and you are done.  The red will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To set this for all emails, as opposed to on an email by email basis:
click on view,
click on view settings,
click on conditional formatting,
ensure overdue email is checked,
click on overdue email,
click on font and set it however you want,
click ok,
click ok again.
problem should now be solved

Answer (score 0):

This happened to us when the user chose to use Outlook’s Resend email option to resend an email that had been sent to them.  User got a warning that they were not the original sender.  After this the user changed the sender to themselves and edited the body and signature.  I believe this is expected behavior given the circumstances.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Appreciate your desire to help, but your post doesn't appear to address the question in a useful manner. Are you saying that Resend always causes this behavior?  Also, this is a very old post with many answers that seem more pertinent.  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.